# How can I scale top and bottom the image with Glide?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, imageview, android-glide

I'm pulling data from the internet with Glide. The parts of the picture that I want to focus on are below or sometimes above the picture. When I scaleType center or centerCrop, it scales towards the center of the image. I want it to focus above or below it. how can I do? Please review the sample image below

[I want this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrgQg.jpg)

```
    <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/slide_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_182sdp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        android:src="@drawable/alide"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:riv_corner_radius="@dimen/_16sdp" />
```

```
String image = mSliderItems.get(position).getImage();

      RequestOptions  options = new RequestOptions()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_placeholder_full)
                .dontAnimate()
                .error(R.drawable.ic_placeholder_full);

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(image)
                .apply(options)
                .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> slideImageLoading(position, slide_image), 1000);
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .into(slide_image);
```

Also, since I'm using it in a recyclerview, I need a structure or library to do this job really lightly and quickly.

Thank you in advance for your help

I searched on the internet but couldn't find a similar problem. check all the scaleTypes but it didn't work. i want something converging that focuses on the top or bottom of the picture

```
public class BottomCropTransformation extends BitmapTransformation {

    public BottomCropTransformation() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap transform(@NonNull BitmapPool pool, @NonNull Bitmap toTransform, int outWidth, int outHeight) {
        final int width = toTransform.getWidth();
        final int height = toTransform.getHeight();
        final int targetHeight = (int) (width * ((float) outHeight / (float) outWidth));

        final Bitmap bitmap = pool.get(width, targetHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        if (bitmap == null) {
            return Bitmap.createBitmap(toTransform, 0, height - targetHeight, width, targetHeight);
        }

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setShader(new BitmapShader(toTransform, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP));

        RectF rectF = new RectF(0, 0, width, targetHeight);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, 0, 0, paint);

        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDiskCacheKey(@NonNull MessageDigest messageDigest) {
        messageDigest.update("BottomCropTransformation".getBytes());
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried creating `android:scaleType="center|top"` or `android:scaleType="center|bottom"`

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'center|bottom'

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide). I think you'll want `FIT_START`.

Comment: @Cheticamp it's actually the `MATRIX` one they need (the `FIT` ones scale the image down to fit inside the view, `START` and `CENTER` etc just position it in the spare space). But Glide doesn't provide that as a basic transformation - honestly you might just want to write your own (https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/400/com/bumptech/glide/load/resource/bitmap/BitmapTransformation.html) and use `Bitmap#createBitmap` to create a cropped version that uses the correct region. Glide's concurrency & caching should make it as performant as possible I think?

Comment: @cactustictacs Good point about `FIT_START` since it won't crop the image but makes sure it all fits.

Comment: but there is a gap in fit start. I don't want it. I want it to fill the screen just like the center crop, but instead of zooming in from the center of the picture, I want it to approach from the bottom or the top.